# Angular binding not working in Web Storm

Tags: angularjs

I'm a starter in angularjs and I'm trying to create a simple event registration site. Here's my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="eventsApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Event Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"/>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/controllers/EventController.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div ng-controller="EventController">
        {{event.name}}
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my app.js:

```
var eventsApp = angular.module('eventsApp', []);
```

And here's my EventController.js:

```
'use strict';

eventsApp.controller('EventController',
function EventController($scope){
    $scope.event = {
        name: 'Driving Class',
        date: '12/19/2015',
        time: '8:00 AM'
    }
});
```

I'm unable to find what I've done wrong here but the binding is not working. No matter what, it just displays {{event.name}} in the browser. I tried both with local angular.js file and also angular cdn. Both doesn't work. The same code worked in plnkr but didn't work in web storm. Is the issue related to the web storm IDE?

Comment: The problem is you haven't closed the script tag, while loading angularjs, it should be closed like </script>

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>`

Comment: This didn't work out either. Still displaying as {{event.name}}

Comment: any error in console then?

Comment: Found the error! There was error loading script files. Corrected that and it's working like a charm. Thank you Pankaj :)

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/varun1989/znqgxv2c/

There may be issue with the way you importing the script.
As pankaj said please close the script tag properly.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js">‌​</script>
```

Comment: As I mentioned before, this works in the plunkr. But I was unable to make it work in my Web Storm IDE. And as Pankaj mentioned, I closed the script tag and still unable to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should look like this

```
eventsApp.controller('EventController', EventController);

function EventController($scope){

}
```

or like this

```
eventsApp.controller('EventController', function($scope) {

);
```

Comment: I tried both of them. Still didn't work. Still displayed as {{event.name}}